# Error on function call for Area2D randomly occurs

Tags: gd, godot, gdscript

I have created a system, within which I am instancing kinematic bodies (2D). These have scripts attached. When I call the functions within these, all is GENERALLY okay. However randomly, with wildly different wait times for it to happen (sometimes it never does), the system will crash, saying that the function, that has been working fine, is does not exist within Area2D. I have no clue why this can happen, can anyone give me any help with this.

The actual error code `Invalid call. Nonexistent function 'move' in base 'Area2D'`

Thanks

Comment: Please include a [minimal and reproduceable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There's little chance of someone helping without knowing what your scene tree looks like, what scripts are attached to nodes, and what signal connections exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add check for method existence before you call method.

Let's say you call `move` method for `obj` variable (replace it with your own).
Now call to the `move` method should look like this:

```
if obj.has_method("move"):
    obj.move()
```

[Docs](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.0/classes/class_object.html#class-object-has-method)